# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' error related to Launch Handler

Tags: ios, swift

I am encountering a runtime issue in my iOS app when interacting with a third-party SDK. The error message is as follows:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'All launch handlers must be registered before application finishes launching.
> libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Assertion failure in -[BGTaskScheduler _unsafe_registerForTaskWithIdentifier:usingQueue:launchHandler:], BGTaskScheduler.m:185

This issue occurs only when my app attempts to access the shared instance of the SDK, and the shared property is underlined in red in Xcode. It seems to be related to background tasks and launch handling.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Close the app completely.
2. Launch the app again.
3. Attempt to access the shared instance of the third-party SDK.

**Code Snippet where the issue occurs:**

```
someSDK.shared.someProperty = someProperty //Error coming while accessing shared.
```

**Questions:**

1. What does the 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' error signify in this context?
2. How can I resolve this issue related to background tasks and the assertion failure in BGTaskScheduler?

Comment: I'd suggest you ask your ThirdParty lib to learn how to register the task. It needs to call `BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier:using:launchHandler:)` at some point. Check if you are missing some setting call (it might be done internally in their SDK but you didn't set it).

Comment: Though, as we are limited to the number of Background Tasks we can register : 1 AppRefresh & 10 ProcessingTask (ie 1 "quick/short", and 10 "long"), it's strange that they are doing it without informing you.

Comment: @Larme can you tell me what this error means, I am not able to understand the error.

Comment: It's about Background Tasks (tasks done when app is not in foreground). You need to register all the background tasks (which id needs to be in the Info.plist). It seems that your SDK fails to do so. Ask to the SDK support.

Comment: Hi @Larme, I added the identifier to plist(BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers) as told in the sdk, but still getting the same crash
So exactly what is happening
Scenario 1: 
my app uses login/logout functionality, login required SDK to be initialized and used and logout requires to shutdown.
When user logged in force close the app and again open app, getting 'Launch handler already been registered'
When user logout,force close app, rerun and login, getting 'All Launch handlers must be registered'

Comment: The SDK needs to call `BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier:using:launchHandler:)`. Ask to the support of your SDK what's wrong and what call you should made to trigger it. Report your error to them. We can't guess as we don't know which SDK it is.